# Models are my life, vs models is my life

Tags: grammatical-number

I am wondering which one of the following is correct:

1. I love building mathematical models. Models are my life.
2. I love building mathematical models. Models is my life.

Comment: "Models is my life" is not technically incorrect if you consider "models" to be a unified concept.  But in most circles it would be better received to say "Modeling is my life", if that suits your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Models* is plural, so it takes the plural verb: *Models are my life* is correct.

You could flip it around and say *My life is models*, and here you use *is* because *my life* is singular.

Both forms are used, and while I favor the first, I cannot say which is more common.

Comment: So saying "Checkers is the game I like best" is wrong???